# How to refresh a listview that presents SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I have a quiz application that stores the result of the user and their username, the topic and the timestamp and have a small issue I am stuck on with putting this data into a listview.

I have noticed that the listview never refreshes, as you can see from the timestamps in the first photo, I have taken 4 quizzes but it doesn't get rid of the results from the previous times I have visited this activity. [Image of the results in the xml activity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoodH.png)  This is what the logcat returns from the log message in display_results.java [Logcat of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnqlc.png)

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FYPSQLApplicationA.db";

    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private SQLiteDatabase SQLITEDATABASE;


    /*Users Table*/
    public static final String USERS = "USERS";
   // public static final String COLUMN_ID = "USER_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "USERNAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "EMAIL";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHRASE = "PHRASE";

    private static final String CREATE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE " + USERS +
            "( " +
            COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY , " +
            COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL , " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT , " +
            COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT , " +
            COLUMN_PHRASE + " TEXT NOT NULL );";

 // MAY INCLUDE A USER ID COLUMN   COLUMN_ID + " INT NOT NULL , " +

    /*Topics Table*/
    public static final String TOPICS = "TOPICS";
    public static final String TOPIC_ID = "TOPIC_ID";
    public static final String TOPIC_NAME = "TOPIC_NAME";
    public static final String CHAPTER_ID = "CHAPTER_ID";
    public static final String CHAPTER_NAME = "CHAPTER_NAME";

    private static final String CREATE_TOPICS = " CREATE TABLE " + TOPICS +
            " ( "
            + TOPIC_ID + " INT PRIMARY KEY , "
            + TOPIC_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL , "
            + CHAPTER_ID + " INT NOT NULL , "
            + CHAPTER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL " + ");";


    /*Results Table*/
    private static final String RESULTS = "RESULTS";
//    private static final String TEST_COLUMN_USERNAME = "USERNAME";
    private static final String COLUMN_SCORE = "SCORE";
//    private static final String COLUMN_TIMES_TAKEN = "TIMES_TAKEN";
    private static final String COLUMN_TIMESTAMP = "TIMESTAMP";



    private static final String CREATE_RESULTS = " CREATE TABLE " + RESULTS +
                " ( 

" +
                COLUMN_USERNAME + "  TEXT NOT NULL , " +
                TOPIC_ID + " INT NOT NULL , " +
                COLUMN_SCORE + " SCORE INT NOT NULL , " +
                COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " TIMESTAMP TEXT NOT NULL , " +
                "FOREIGN KEY(TOPIC_ID) REFERENCES TOPICS(TOPIC_ID) " +
                "FOREIGN KEY(USERNAME) REFERENCES USERS(USERNAME) " + "); ";


    /*Questions Table*/
    private static final String QUESTIONS = "QUESTIONS";
    private static final String QUESTIONS_ID = "QUESTION_ID";
    private static final String QUESTIONTEXT = "QUESTION";
    private static final String ANSWER_A = "ANSWER_A"; //option a
    private static final String ANSWER_B = "ANSWER_B"; //option b
    private static final String ANSWER_C = "ANSWER_C"; //option c
    private static final String QUESTION_ANSWER = "ANSWER"; //correct option

    private static final String CREATE_QUESTIONS = " CREATE TABLE " +
            QUESTIONS + " ( " +
            TOPIC_ID + " INT NOT NULL , " +
            QUESTIONS_ID + " INT PRIMARY KEY , " +
            QUESTIONTEXT + " TEXT NOT NULL , " +
            ANSWER_A + " TEXT NOT NULL , " +
            ANSWER_B + " TEXT NOT NULL , " +
            ANSWER_C + " TEXT NOT NULL , " +
            QUESTION_ANSWER + " INT NOT NULL , " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(TOPIC_ID) REFERENCES TOPICS(TOPIC_ID) " + "); ";



    private static Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context c, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(c, name, factory, version);
    }
    public DatabaseHelper(Context c) {
        super(context = c, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        SQLITEDATABASE = db;
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TOPICS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUESTIONS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_RESULTS);
        addQuestions();
        addTopics();
        this.SQLITEDATABASE = db;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        String queryuser = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USERS;
        String queryquestion = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + QUESTIONS;
        String querytopic = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TOPICS;
        String queryresult = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + RESULTS;

        db.execSQL(queryuser);
        db.execSQL(queryquestion);
        db.execSQL(querytopic);
        db.execSQL(queryresult);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }








    public void insertScore (ScoreDetails SD) {
        SQLITEDATABASE = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, SD.GetUsername());
        values.put(TOPIC_ID, SD.GetTopic());
        values.put(COLUMN_SCORE, SD.GetScore());
        values.put(COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, SD.getCurrentTimeStamp());


        SQLITEDATABASE.insert(RESULTS, null, values);
        SQLITEDATABASE.close();
    }


    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<ScoreDetails> getAllResults() {
        List<ScoreDetails> ResultList = new ArrayList<ScoreDetails>();
        // Select All Query



          GlobalVariables GlobalUser = new GlobalVariables();

/*        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + RESULTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);*/

        String log = "global username "+ GlobalUser.GetUsername();
        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);

        String log11 = " SELECT * FROM RESULTS WHERE " + " USERNAME = " +  " '" + username  +  "' " ;
        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("LOG QUERY Name: ", log11);

                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM RESULTS WHERE " + " USERNAME = " +
                " '" + username  +  "' ", null);

/*        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + RESULTS + " WHERE USERNAME = ?";*/

/*        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{GlobalUser.GetUsername()});*/

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ScoreDetails SD = new ScoreDetails();
                SD.SetUsername(cursor.getString(0));
                SD.SetTopic(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                SD.SetScore(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
                SD.SetCurrentTimeStamp(cursor.getString(3));

                String name = cursor.getString(0) +"\n"+ cursor.getString(1) +"\n"+ cursor.getString(2)
                        +"\n"+ cursor.getString(3);
               Display_results.ArrayofResults.add(name);
                // Adding contact to list
                ResultList.add(SD);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return contact list
        return ResultList;
    }  


}
```

Display_results.java

```
public class Display_results extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView gridView;
public static ArrayList<String> ArrayofResults = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_results_layout);

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            List<ScoreDetails> results = db.getAllResults(GlobalVariables.getInstance().GetUsername());

    for (ScoreDetails SD : results) {
        String log = "Id: "+ SD.GetUsername()
                +" ,Name: " + SD.GetTopic()
                + " ,Phone: " + SD.GetScore()
                + " ,Phone: " + SD.getCurrentTimeStamp() ;
        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);

    }

    /*db.close();*/

    gridView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayofResults);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

/*
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + RESULTS + " WHERE USERNAME =?";

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{GlobalUser.GetUsername()});
```

Comment: I got an error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{p12225720.bill_gates/p12225720.bill_gates.Display_results}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null" it was on the username in the new string line

Comment: Which means that  GlobalUser.GetUsername() is giving a null value and not an username as you expected. Try to log GlobalUser.GetUsername() to see what's happening.

Comment: I changed the line in the display_results to "        List<ScoreDetails> results = db.getAllResults(GlobalVariables.getInstance().GetUsername());" . I used a log message and the output showed it was getting the correct username now.

Comment: The log message helped me track it, It works now, thank you. Do you have any idea how to fix my second issue as now it will only retrieve the value of the username but the result list does not get rid of old results on the list, so if I check with one account and then log out and log back in with another account it will still show the old results from when I checked with the former account and not just the latter.

Comment: I looks like you are only adding results  (Display_results.ArrayofResults.add(name);) to your array and never clearing it. So it will only grow after every query.

Comment: Ok, how would I go about achieving that? That is because I am currently trying to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but it does not appear to be working.

Comment: Well you could do something like this: ArrayofResults.clear() before adding new results.

Comment: Cheers, that has worked a treat, I will correct answer your original answer. Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use Recycler View instead of ListView, but this is not what you asked for.

You never call insertScore ?

Comment: insertscore is called in another activity but the result is put into the database fine, I can add that activity if that helps.